# Openbravo ERP Joomla Virtuemart Integration/Synchronisation

Tags: joomla, virtuemart, erp, openbravo

Do someone knows an `Joomla Component/Module/Plugin` which can make the Integration or Synchronisation between `OpenBravo` and `Virtuemart`?

Answer (score 1):

There isn't any current plugin or component that does this currently. Looks like someone was working on it like two years ago (http://forum.virtuemart.net/index.php?topic=78087.0)

Your best bet at would probably be to develop a plugin for Virtuemart that connect into OpenBravo's rest API.